# Handling Reserved Characters in URL

Tags: django, url

So I am trying to write a simple API using Django that uses the twitter API to send tweets for users. I have:

```
url(r'^(?P<twitter_id>\d+)/send_tweet/(?P<text>(.){,140})$', views.send_tweet, name='send_tweet'),
```

and a view send_tweet that takes two parameters twitter_id and text and sends text as a tweet for that user

The issue I am having is if text is a string with reserved characters like "1. #Hello" . Then the #Hello is not included in the text parameter.

I have pinpointed that this is because '#' and '?' and others are reserved characters in URLs. So I attempted to pass text as part of the querystring and access it with `text = request.GET.get('text')` in the view, but that had the same problem.

Is there anyway to get around this and read characters like # or ? from the url or query string? And if not, what would be a good solution for having the user pass their text to tweet to my API (I.e forcing the user to pass an encoding string, and then decoding within the view perhaps)?

Edit: So if I force the user to pass in an already encoded string to the URL it works (string_of_characters_like_these%3A%24%23%40%3D%3F%25%5EQ%5E%24). But is this a fair requirement to make in an API?

Comment: This really is just an abuse of the url/query string. The text should be in the body of the url, either as encoded form data or as json.

Answer (score 0):

It's not reasonable to expect the user to do that. Why not apply [`urllib.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) for them?

Comment: Where would I apply that? I can't call it inside the view, since the parameter is already passed at that point. Sorry if that's an obvious question, but I am very new to web dev

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your setup and got things backwards. It sounds like you should be calling `decode` inside your view after they send it.